# Why does this "find" command scan all directories?

Tags: bash, script, bash-scripting

I only want to recursively scan `Documents` and not leave that "parent" folder.  My script scans recursively my entire file system, and I am not sure what element of this script is causing that to occur.  This is what I have:

```
#/bin/sh
for f in $(find /home/rmintz/Documents/ -type f -name "*jpg")
do
  echo $f
done
```

What do I need to alter so that this bash script only scans the `Documents` folder and nothing else?

I am given the impression that this is scanning my entire file system as the output in terminal shows directories outside of the realm of `/home/rmintz/Documents`.

An example is `/usr/lib`.

Comment: Can you give an example of results that contradict your expectations?

Comment: If I comment out the `fi` (why do you have it there if there is no `if` that belongs to it?), the code works correctly for me.

Comment: @Adalee - the fi was part of syntax I had commented out, instead of removing the line from my post, I accidentally just deleted the #.  Post updated.

Comment: @TobySpeight - edited post to answer your ? -- I see directories outside the realm of Documents being output to terminal during the scan

Comment: Does the same happen if you run `find /home/rmintz/Documents/ -type f -name "*jpg" -exec echo {} \;` ?

Comment: @user2676140 Can you add more details? What OS are you using, etc? Doesn't matter where I run the script from, I can't reproduce your issue

Comment: @slhck - that syntax does not leave the directory.  (Works as I would expect)

Comment: Can you show a little example output of your script? Not just the "erroneou" line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using an anti-pattern, in that you should never use a `for` loop to iterate over the output of a `find` command. It's a little similar to [parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), which you should also never do.

Instead, use `find`'s built in ability to run commands:

```
find /home/rmintz/Documents/ -type f -name "*jpg" -exec echo {} \;
```

Here, the `{}` is replaced with the name of every file or directory found.

If you wanted to use a loop (e.g. for more complicated operations), you would have to delimit each file path with a NULL character, which is what the `-print0` option does, and use `while` and `read` to parse that output:

```
find /home/rmintz/Documents/ -type f -name "*jpg" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

If you don't do that but stick to parsing the output of `find`, the arguments to `for` will actually be split on every whitespace character. This means that files with a space in their name would actually show up as two separate files for `echo`. Also, if your file list was too long, you would exceed the maximum argument size for a command. This is where the pipe helps in the second example.

In your specific example, I don't know why it would output a path like `/usr/lib`, as that could only be the case if you had an actual forward slash in the filename, e.g. if your file was called `/usr/lib foo.jpg`.